# Gupshup - Template Messaging - Message does not match WhatsApp HSM template

Tags: templates, whatsapp, gupshup

I am using GupShup V1 API for sending WhatsApp messages. Its a Template message. So we have submitted our template and WhatsApp has approved it.

Template

```
Your payment for {{1}} has been received 

Paid: {{2}}
date: {{3}}
ID: {{4}}

Thank you for trusting {{5}}.
```

And below is the text that I am sending in the API

```
"Your payment for product has been received \nPaid: amount\ndate: transactiondate\nID: transactionID\n\nThank you for trusting NAME.\n"
```

Also tried without the '\n' at the end.

But I am getting the below error

```
{:error=>"Message does not match WhatsApp HSM template."}
```

Any leads will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Goto templates dashboard and check how is the text displayed. There is a option to test the api as part of the dashboard.  Try that

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set isTemplate = true for this to work.